# Looping in javascript through a list of users

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, frontend

I have a list of users store in an array

```json
accountsade: [
    {
        id: 0.4387810413935975
        name: "Adrian"
        password: "345"
        userName: "nathanael"
    },
    {
        id: 0.2722524232951682
        name: "Nathan"
        password: "123"
        userName: "nathanaelmbale45"
    }
],
```

And I want to loop through the list of users and capture the values `password`, and `username`
of every single object in the array and compare them to already existing variables.

```
usernameL = "nathanaelmbale45"
passwordL = "123"
```

Comment: Definitely not a good idea to authenticate front-end. With the use of developer tools, anyone can gain access to every single username and password.

Comment: It is also a security fundamental that passwords be hashed, and not stored in plain text.

Comment: Appart from that, you are looking for [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    let accountsade = [
        {
            id: 0.4387810413935975,
            name: "Adrian",
            password: "345",
            userName: "nathanael",
        },
        {
            id: 0.2722524232951682,
            name: "Nathan",
            password: "123",
            userName: "nathanaelmbale45"
        }
    ]
    let userName = 'nathanael', password = '345';
    let account = accountsade.filter((item) => {
        return item.userName === userName && item.password == password;
    });
    console.log(account);
</script>
```

-----------# output #-----------------

```
[{"id":0.4387810413935975,"name":"Adrian","password":"345","userName":"nathanael"}]
```

Comment: Some explanation on your code would be nice. But am upvoting anyway.

Comment: sure, if you want to filter records from the array, instead of using for loop, the best approach is to use the .filter function, for more details open the following link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: Good idea. But I meant to say you should add that explanation as being with your solution.

Comment: yes sure, I will add an explanation onward, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. to capture just map over the array and return the required fields

objectArrap.map(object=>({object.property, object.property2}))

to compare you can use similar methods called filter and find. If you need to do something specialized consider looping over each object with objectsArrray.foreach

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, doing this in client side code would be a BAD idea because you expose all of your usernames and passwords to something that can be easily found in the browser console...

For the sake of understanding array functions though... this will return the first matching object in the array based on matching username and password.

```js
var accountsade = [
  {
    id: 0.4387810413935975,
    name: "Adrian",
    password: "345",
    userName: "nathanael"
  },
  {
    id: 0.2722524232951682,
    name: "Nathan",
    password: "123",
    userName: "nathanaelmbale45"
  }
];

var usernameL = "nathanaelmbale45";
var passwordL = "123";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// array.find takes as its arrgument a function that gets run
// against each element of the array
//
// array.find will return the current element being supplied
// the first time the provided function returns a "true" value
//
// if the provided function always returns a "false" value...
// then array.find will return the value "undefined"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var authUser = accountsade.find(function(element) {
  var returnValue = true;
  returnValue &= element.userName == usernameL;
  returnValue &= element.password == passwordL;
  return returnValue
});

console.log(authUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: authenticating users like this is not safe. I'll tell you why in a minute, but let's solve your actual question first.

You can use JavaScript's [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to fetch the right object in the list. Then, you can check if that object's password matches the input:

```js
const json = {
    accountsade: [
        {
            id: 0.4387810413935975,
            name: "Adrian",
            password: "345",
            userName: "nathanael"
        },
        {
            id: 0.2722524232951682,
            name: "Nathan",
            password: "123",
            userName: "nathanaelmbale45"
        }
    ]
};

const usernameL = "nathanaelmbale45";
const passwordL = "123";

alert(checkLogin(usernameL, passwordL));

function checkLogin(username, password) {
    const account = json.accountsade.find(account => {
      return account.userName = username;
    });
    return account.password == password;
}
```

### Proper authentication

he goal of authenticating a user is to make sure that a user is who he/she says he/she is. That way, you can decide in your code what actions a user can take.

This process should be doe in the back end (server side) of your application, to make sure that the user can't see and manipulate it. If you send all of the account data over to the front end (your user's computer), that person can see all of that data and use other user's passwords to log in.

You also didn't [hash the passwords](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/) (scramble their contents in a non-reversable way). This should even be done when handling authentication server side, as your database could be compromised and leaked by another security failure.

Another downside of sending all account data to the front end, is bandwith. Suppose you have a million user's, that will take a lot of redundant time and resources just to log the user in.

So the right way is: send the username and password that the user entered [via a secure connection](https://www.howtogeek.com/181767/htg-explains-what-is-https-and-why-should-i-care/) (so nobody can eavesdrop), fetch the hashed password from the database, hash the password that the user entered and compare it too the fetched hash. If they match exactly, the user is legitimate and can be logged in (set the appropriate cookies server side or send an [authentication token](https://auth0.com/learn/token-based-authentication-made-easy/#!)).

Now those are the basics, but it's safer to use proven solutions like frameworks and libraries that do this work for you instead of building this yourself (lots of users have looked at the code already and improved it, you on the other hand might make a mistake/create a security risk).

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkLogin(usernameL, passwordL) {
  const account = accountsade.find((account) => {
    return (account.userName = usernameL && account.password == passwordL);
  });
  return account;
}
```

that would be the best practice i could think of right now. but why would you make a auth-system in frontend?